# MapGeneratorEditor.OnInspectorGUI() No suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging

I have recently been following a tutorial series on Procedurally Generated world generation, I am fairly new to coding and I have come across the following problem. I have 3 error messages in my code,

The first error says:
Error   CS0115  'MapGeneratorEditor.OnInspectorGUI()': no suitable method found to override

The second says:
Error   CS0103  The name 'target' does not exist in the current context

And the third error is:
Error   CS0103  The name 'DrawDefaultInspector' does not exist in the current context

I think that these are somehow related to each other
I am using Unity 2019.4.16f1 personal and here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGeneratorEditor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        MapGenerator mapGen = (MapGenerator)target;

        DrawDefaultInspector();

        if(GUILayout.Button("Generate"))
        {
            mapGen.GenerateMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inheriting your **MapGeneratorEditor** class from MonoBehavior, but **OnInspectorGUI** function only member of **Editor** class. You should replace **MonoBehavior** with **Editor**

> MapGeneratorEditor:Editor

here is referances where your functions comes

[OnInspectorGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.OnInspectorGUI.html)

[DrawDefaultInspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.DrawDefaultInspector.html)